# ASP.NET MVC model from db

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model

I created my model from DB in which I have tables Users, Roles and UsersInRoles which is an intermediary table between the first 2.
My question is how do I take specific users where Roles = something since the table UsersInRoles is not added to the model?

```
public partial class Role
    {
        public Role()
        {
            this.Users = new HashSet<User>();
        }

        public int RoleID { get; set; }
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        public string RoleDescription { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }

public partial class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            this.Roles = new HashSet<Role>();
        }

        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    }

public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var users = db.Users;
            return View(users.ToList());
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will work...

```
        var usersInRole = db.Users.Where(x => x.Roles.Any(y => y.RoleId == roleid));
```

Answer (score 0):

I admittedly haven't had much experience with HashSets, but is there any reason a simple Linq query wouldn't work?

```
var requestedUsers = from UsersInRoles 
                     in db.Users 
                     where UsersInRoles.Roles.Contains(DesiredRoleHere) 
                     select UsersInRoles;
```